# jQuery Div parent and child

Tags: jquery

Right, lets say I have these repeated divs.

```
<div class="upcoming">
<div class="roll" style="display:none">Hidden</div>
</div>
<div class="upcoming">
<div class="roll" style="display:none">Hidden</div>
</div>
<div class="upcoming">
<div class="roll" style="display:none">Hidden</div>
</div>
```

This is incorrect, but how do I operate this using jQuery to reveal the "roll" class held inside when hovering over one of those divs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $(".upcoming").hover(function() {
        $(this + ".roll").fadeIn("Fast");
    }, function() {
        $(this + ".roll).fadeOut("Fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: Don't really know jquery but how about $(this).$('.roll').fadeIn(...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`jQuery(expression, context)`](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) form:

```
$('.roll', this)
```

Comment: Excellent! I used this for looping through all the divs on my page which had child elements within them and had to find/print the value of multiple child elements within each div.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(function() {  
  $("div.upcoming").hover(function() {
    $("div.roll", this).fadeIn("fast");
  }, function() {
    $("div.roll", this).fadeOut("fast");
  });
});
```

Just a general tip: wherever possible with both jQuery and CSS be specific in your selectors. Try to use class selectors with no tag as a last resort.

- Best: #id
- Good: tag or tag.class
- Worst: .class

Why? Well, a selector like ".upcoming" has to basically traverse the entire tree or subtree. Theere are DOM methods to speed up the other two (getElementById or getElementsByName respectively). It can make a significant difference to page load times.

Answer (score -1):

In this specific case

```
$(this).next()
```

would also give you a reference to child .roll div.